# Check if traffic is gzipped

Tags: networking, tcpdump, compression

I have an application server running on port 80. How can I check if the incoming and outgoing traffic is gzipped? Also, the application communicates with another server (also HTTP requests). I'd like to check these connections are compressed as well.

Can this be done with tcpdump? How?

Thanks

Comment: Please do not cross post on stack exchange. An answer is already [here](http://superuser.com/questions/621227/check-if-http-calls-are-gzipped).

Answer (score -1):

Use `ncat` to proxy the data, and dump it to a file.

```
ncat -o out -lk 90 -c "ncat localhost 80"
```

This will save all connection data that comes in on 90, save it, and then forward it to port 80. You could just read the file to find if it's in plain text, or extract the information of interest and run `file` over it.